# Copying and pasting from multiple workbooks into one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a code that will copy and paste some scattered cell values from all workbooks from a file and paste all the information into one single spreadsheet. I'm getting a message error back saying: "Run-time error '1004': Sorry, we couldn't find D:\TESTES\05 MAIO\0335-2021- DEPEN - MINISTRIO DA SEGURANCA PUBLICA DF - ITEM 3 - SEDAN - 109 UND.XLSX. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cgr8.png)

This is the code I'm writing:

```
Sub Find_Files()
        
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    fldr.Show
    f = fldr.SelectedItems(1)
    f = f & "\"
    
    ibox = InputBox("File Must Contain (Note * wildcards can be used)", , "*.xlsx*")
    'On Error GoTo ext
    
    sn = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & f & ibox & """ /s /a /b").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)
     
    files.Cells.Clear
    files.Cells(1).Resize(UBound(sn) + 1) = Application.Transpose(sn)



oarray = files.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
rprw = kpi.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 1

For rw = LBound(oarray) To UBound(oarray)
    Debug.Print oarray(rw, 1)
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(oarray(rw, 1))
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 1) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C3")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 2) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C4")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 3) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C5")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 4) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C6")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 5) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C7")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 6) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("C8")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 7) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("g3")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 8) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("c12")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 9) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("d12")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 10) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("e12")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 11) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("f12")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 12) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("H12")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 13) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("I12")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 14) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("j12")
    kpi.Cells(rprw, 15) = wb.Sheets(1).Range("L12")
    wb.Close
    rprw = rprw + 1
Next

ext:

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(oarray(rw, 1))

End Sub
```

This is where they are supposed to be pasted to:

[Excel Workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdN6H.png)

I don't know why it says it can't find the files.

Comment: You have declared 2 variables but use many more - it would also be easier to debug if you used descriptive variable names. What is `sn`, `oarray` and `rprw`?

Comment: Is there actually a file with that name at that path?  The name shown in the screenshot is different from the name you posted in the text of the post - which one is correct?

Comment: I finally got it up and running. There were actually two mistakes in the code above. The first one is that it was trying to paste some value on the first cell of the kpi workbook which was merged with others in a row. The second one was that some characters in my language(Portuguese) were creating some error messages as well. Thank you both for your observations Samuel Everson & Tim Williams!